# Bootstrap Modal from code-behind not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Need to open a modal when the password or user are incorrect it will stay in **Else** .. however, does not work , it does not work does not open the modal

```
protected void bntLogar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Registrar criptografia = new Registrar();

        if (Login.logarUsuario(txtUser.Text, criptografia.CriptografiaMD5(txtSenha.Text)))
        {
            //Cria um cookie do lado do servidor
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("estado", "conectado");

            //Define a validade do cookie (10 dias a partir de hoje)
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12);

            //Envia o cookie para o cliente
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

            //Redireciona para a pagina inicial
            Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");

            //fortawsome
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
        }

    }
```

And I put inside the  JavaScript code

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModal() {
            $('#modalLogin').modal('show');
        }
    </script>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLogin" runat="server" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Warning</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Watch out! Your about to be locked out.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The tah `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>`in this sitemaster

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Informations invalides');", true);
```

instead of

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
```

but i don't know if it'll solve your problem.

Comment: Appeared aletar , is an alternative , thank you.
But really need the modal , it is by design requirement.

Comment: yeah, i mean, use the modal, but use RegisterStartupScript() instead of RegisterClientScriptBlock()  that what i was trying to say